# Spring boot tests fail

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot. I have a project(war file) that depends on another module as a jar file for data signing. On IntelliJ when I do a "maven test" The tests just run and fine. But if I go to project explorer right click on green java tests folder and choose "run all tests" My tests fail due to missing libraries etc:

```
Error:(7, 31) java: package org.bouncycastle.crypto does not exist
Error:(8, 31) java: package org.bouncycastle.crypto does not exist
Error:(12, 38) java: package org.bouncycastle.crypto.params does not exist
Error:(18, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SignerWithRecovery
Error:(25, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Digest


  location: class com.mySigner
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the classpath ([`Use classpath of module`](http://imgur.com/a/vtalh) drop-down list if) which is being created for the _folder_ run configuration. It may be different than what you'd expect...

Answer (score 0):

That looks like missing dependencies, so, that's giving a hint that  dependencies of yours are not in proper scope, please try to add 
 bouncycastle dependancies with proper scope. E.g.

```
<scope>test</scope>
```